# Using external php script for checks

Tags: php, mysql

i am currently building one of my newest websites which is a browser based game, i have normally never really used include scripts, only for headers etc.. However this time i need to check if the user has reached a certain level to enable them to receive a award, however i have over 50 awards, which need to be checked to see if they reach the requirement to get it + the code that changes their account to meet the award, which obviously with over 50 awards will require quite a bit of code. Could i build an external script that does all this and then just use the include function to run the script?

Thanks for the help and sorry if this is confusing

Comment: I'm sorry, what? I read that three times and I'm still not sure what you're asking. Remotely hosted PHP script? You just want to know if you can include a file? Something else?

Comment: please be more abstract and more focused in your question. eliminate all application specific info so we can understand what it is you want exactly. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could i build [a][...] script that does all this and then just use the include function to run the script?

Yes you can, that's normally the purpose of [`include`](http://php.net/include).